# Let $\sigma \in S_n∖A_n$ ($\sigma$ not in $A_n$), prove that the order of $\sigma$ is even.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Given $\sigma \in S_n\setminus A_n$, prove that the order of $\sigma$ is even.

I feel that I have a way to prove it:

Since $\sigma \notin A_n$, the sign of $\sigma$ is $-1$.

This implies that $(-1)^{n-t}=-1$, where $t$ is the number of foreign symmetries that assemble $\sigma$. This gives

$$n-t\equiv 1\bmod 2$$

and then I'm stuck.

I will be glad to see somebody continue or prove it in another way.

Comment: If $\sigma^k = e$, then $1 = sgn(e) = sgn(\sigma)^k = (-1)^k$

Comment: What is $[S_n : A_n]$?

Comment: But $S_n/A_n\cong C_2$. It has one element of even order and one of odd order. Did you mean $S_n\setminus A_n$?

Comment: yes i mean Sn∖An!!!

Answer (score 3):

$A_n$ is normal in $S_n$ and $S_n / A_n$ is the group of order 2. The kernel of the quotient map $\theta : S_n \longrightarrow S_n / A_n$ is $A_n$. So under $\theta$, $S_n \setminus A_n$ maps to the element of order 2 in $S_n / A_n$. Hence every element in $S_n \setminus A_n$ must have even order.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma$ can be written in the products of disjoint $k$-cycles $\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_r$.
Then $|\sigma|=[|\sigma_1|, \cdots, |\sigma_r|]$. Note $|\sigma_i|$ is odd if and only if $\sigma_i \in A_n$. Hence if $|\sigma|$ is odd, then $|\sigma_i|$ are even permutation, and $\sigma \in A_n$. This implies $|\sigma|$ is even.

Comment: i don't understand. What do you mean with $|\sigma|=[|\sigma_1|, \cdots, |\sigma_r|]$?

Comment: This is the way to compute the order of a permutation.

Comment: Please, Teach me how you compute the order of permutation.

Comment: 1) every permutation can be the products of disjoint cycles. 2) every $k$-cycles are order $k$. 3) the order of this permutation is the least common multiply of the orders of these disjoint cycles. I believe this can be find in any textbooks of algebar or group theory.